# VB Visual Basic 2015 how to set name using string?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, variables, object

I have many picterbox objects like **mybox1001big, mybox1002big, mybox1003big** etc.

I want in code choice name using some string or integer like:

```
Dim ident as integer
ident = 1002
mybox[ident]big.Image = temporary.Image
```

...but this don't work. What is the solution?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: just can't see solution, how to use it to my problem?

Comment: You get better responses when you tag your question appropriately. VBA is *NOT* vb.net!

Comment: `ControlCollection.Find()` <-> `Me.Controls` \*AHEM\*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Controls` collection to find a control by its name.

The below code assumes that the control is directly on the form surface. If it is nested within some other control, replace `Me` with that control name appropriately:

```
Dim ident as integer
ident = 1002
Me.Controls("mybox" & ident.ToString & "big").Image = temporary.Image
```

Comment: Thanks.
Have one problem:
picTEMP1.Image = Me.Controls("mag" & SWAPA.ToString & "box").Image

After "=" is red error, so i can replace "me" to something else but don't have idea what put here...

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want a method to go round all the form containers for PictureBox's then you could use this method;

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetControlsOfType<T>(Control root)
where T : Control
{
var t = root as T;
if (t != null) yield return t;

var container = root as ContainerControl;
if (container != null)
    foreach (Control c in container.Controls)
        foreach (var i in GetControlsOfType<T>(c))
            yield return i;
}
```

Then do something like this

```
ident = 1002
foreach (var pictureBox in GetControlsOfType<PictureBox>(theForm)) 
{
    //Then use Pradeeps code here
    //Me.Controls("mybox" & ident.ToString & "big").Image = temporary.Image
    ident++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution?

```
Dim ident As Integer = 1002
Dim name = String.Format("mybox{0}big", ident)
Dim elem = TryCast(Me.Controls(name), picturebox)
If elem IsNot Nothing Then elem.Image = ...
```

But this is for object's, how to use it for variables?

```
Dim something1001this, something1002this, something1003this etc...
Dim ident As Integer = 1002
    Dim name = ... ?
```